# How to export the project as zip and import the project from a zip in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to export the project as zip and import the project from a zip React

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and this [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Code that you've worked on to solve the problem should include a [mcve], and be included in your question.

Comment: We gonna need you to give a bit more info than that, use case, aim, reason, background, limitations etc`